# Array operations in a loop parallelization with openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize for loops which are based on array operations. However, I cannot get expected speedup. I guess the way of parallelization is wrong in my implementation.

Here is one example:

```
    curr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*nx + sizeof(char)*nx*ny);
    next = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*nx + sizeof(char)*nx*ny);

    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(nx,ny) firstprivate(curr) schedule(static)
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++){
        curr[i] = (char*)(curr+nx) + i*ny;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(nx,ny) firstprivate(next) schedule(static)
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++){
        next[i] = (char*)(next+nx) + i*ny;
    }
```

And here is another:

```
int i,j, sum = 0, probability = 0.2;     
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) firstprivate(curr) schedule(static)
for(i=1;i<nx-1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<ny-1;j++) {
        curr[i][j] = (real_rand() < probability);
        sum += curr[i][j];
    }
}
```

Is there any problematic mistake in my way? How can I improve this?

Comment: It would help a lot diagnosing your problem if you were to specify the values of `nx` and `ny` that you are using. Also, what is `real_rand()` doing? How are you measuring speedup?

Comment: nx and ny are the sizes of char **, basically the number of rows and columns. Also, nx = ny. read_rand() returns a random number between 0 and 1. I measure speedup by execution time. I tried with 16 threads, it is reduced from 33 to 23 but the expected execution time is around 4 seconds. This is not the only part to parallelize but if I figure out to improve these, then I can complete the rest.

Comment: You did not answer my question. What are the values of `nx` and `ny`? 1? 5? 10? 100? 10000000? Also, `real_rand()` is calling `rand()` or another PRNG that uses a global state or some thread-local PRNGs?

Comment: In my try, nx=ny=2000, rand calls drand48 function

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the work done by each thread is very little and the overhead from the OpenMP runtime is negating and speedup from the parallel execution. You may try combining both parallel regions together to reduce the overhead, but it won't help much:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(int i=0;i<nx;i++){
    curr[i] = (char*)(curr+nx) + i*ny;
    next[i] = (char*)(next+nx) + i*ny;
}
```

In the second case, the bottleneck is the call to `drand48()`, buried somewhere in the call to `real_rand()`, and the summation. `drand48` uses a global state that is shared between all threads. In single-threaded applications, the state is usually kept in the L1 data cache and there `drand48` is really fast. In your case, when one thread updates the state, this change propagates to the other cores and invalidates their caches. Consequently, when the other threads call `drand48`, the state has to be fetched again from the memory (or shared L3 cache). This introduces huge delays and makes `dran48` much slower than when used in a single-threaded program. The same applies to the summation in `sum`, which also computes the wrong value due to data races.

The solution to the first problem is to have separate PRNG per thread, e.g., use `erand48()` and pass a thread-local value for `xsubi`. You have to also seed each PRNG with a different value to avoid correlated pseudorandom streams. The solution of the data race is to use OpenMP reductions:

```
int sum = 0;
double probability = 0.2;     
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) reduction(+:sum) schedule(static)
for(int i=1;i<nx-1;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<ny-1;j++) {
        curr[i][j] = (real_rand() < probability);
        sum += curr[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, I thought I had to declare arrays as firstprivate even though threads do not interfere with each other.  Is it okay to remove firstprivate clauses?

Comment: Your arrays are actually pointers. What you are doing is declaring each pointer to be firstprivate, which doesn’t make much sense since you are not modifying their values. It is ok to leave shared variable that are only read and never written shared. There is only one exception - if the variable is in the same cache line as another variable that is being written to. This will trigger a problem known as false sharing and then you need to make it firstprivate even though you are not modifying its value.